# Finding probability of a team winning the title given probability of future matches

Tags: probability

Say, we have two teams: Manchester City and Liverpool. Both of them have 3 games remaining with the following probabilities of winning/drawing:

```
Manchester City (win) --> 76%, 72%, 70%

Manchester City (draw) --> 10%, 17%, 19%

Liverpool (win) --> 65%, 79%, 77%

Liverpool (draw) --> 21%, 13%, 16%
```

Also, current score in the league is Man City (93) and Liverpool (90)

Assuming there are only two teams competing for the title (there are more teams but they have no chance of winning the title) in this league, I want to find the probability of Man City winning the league.

Scores alotted: Win (3 points), Loss (0 points), Draw (1 point)

Comment: Assuming independence, the coefficients of x^n in the expansion of `(0.76 x^3 + 0.10 x + 0.14)*(0.72 x^3 + 0.17 x + 0.11)*(0.70 x^3 + 0.19 x + 0.11)` will give you the chances of Man City scoring n additional points, where the constant term is the chance of Man City losing. You can do a similar calculation for Liverpool and compare. Not making this an answer because I suspect there's an easier way to do it (perhaps by using a 'y' polynomial for Liverpool and multiplying)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy enough to enumerate all possible outcomes and sum up the probabilities of the outcomes where Man City wins the title.

In R:

```
# all possible outcomes (1 = win, 2 = draw); Man = columns 1:3
outcomes <- expand.grid(rep(list(1:3), 6))
points <- outcomes - (outcomes < 3L)
# filter outcomes where Man wins (Liverpool get fewer than 3 more points than Man)
outcomes <- outcomes[rowSums(points[,4:6]) - rowSums(points[,1:3]) < 3L,]
probs <- matrix(c(0.76,0.1,0.72,0.17,0.7,0.19,0.65,0.21,0.79,0.13,0.77,0.16), 2)
probs <- rbind(probs, 1 - colSums(probs)) # probability of loss
sum(Rfast::rowprods(matrix(probs[unlist(outcomes + (col(outcomes) - 1L)*3L)], ncol = 6)))
#> [1] 0.8650188
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had a couple of clarification questions:

- If needed, how would you expand this code for more than 2 teams (dynamically)?

- I thought the current score of 93 (Man) and 90 (Liv) would also have an effect on the probability. Why doesn't it?

Comment: `outcomes` and `probs` have the same number of columns as games to be played (here, 3 Man City games + 3 Liverpool games). More teams or more games means more columns. With many more games and/or teams, this approach will fail due to combinatorial explosion.

Comment: It does account for the current score: `outcomes <- outcomes[rowSums(points[,4:6]) - rowSums(points[,1:3]) < 3L,]` (could be changed to `outcomes <- outcomes[rowSums(points[,4:6]) - rowSums(points[,1:3]) < 93L - 90L,]`.

Comment: got it! Thanks!